# Efficiently turning tabular data (array of objects) into a square matrix with JavaScript/d3.js

Tags: javascript, matrix, d3.js, chord-diagram

I have a programming problem related to transforming data from one form to another.

I have an array of objects representing a table of data that needs to be transformed into a matrix for a visualization. I somehow avoided covering matrix math during my education, so apologies if my terminology is incorrect.

---

More specifically, I have an array of objects representing formatted data:

```
var pokes = [
    {source: "Harry", target: "Maria", type: "poke"},
    {source: "Brin", target: "Serge", type: "poke"},
    {source: "Maria", target: "Brin", type: "poke"},
    {source: "Serge", target: "Simon", type: "poke"},
    {source: "Brin", target: "Serge", type: "poke"}
];
```

And I need to turn it into a square matrix for use with a chord diagram, e.g.:

```
var matrix = [
    [0, 5, 2, 1, 4],
    [7, 0, 8, 4, 7],
    [9, 4, 0, 3, 1],
    [8, 5, 5, 0, 8],
    [6, 3, 9, 2, 0]
];
```

The length/width of the resulting matrix, n, equals the number of unique individuals in the array (Harry, Serge, etc), and the value in the corresponding cell (x, y) is the number of times person x poked person y. Each object in the pokes array represents one poke (the "type" property doesn't affect the construction of the matrix).

---

So, for example, the object:

```
{source: "Brin", target: "Serge", type: "poke"}
```

would add 1 to the cell that represents (Brin, Serge).

---

This is my pseudocode method:

```
Create array, people, containing list of unique people in pokes (both source and target).
Create empty array, matrix.
For each person in people:
    Create an array, foo, of size people.length.
    For each poke in pokes:  
        If person == poke.source:
            Add 1 to foo[x] where x is the index of poke.target in people.
    Push foo into matrix.
```

I haven't progressed into real code because I am not sure that this method is:

1. Correct
2. Efficient/fast, especially if pokes.length approaches thousands

Any advice would be appreciated;  especially if d3.js has a hidden method for creating matrices that I haven't spotted.

Comment: It'd be faster if you didn't iterate over the whole poke array for each person.